# How to control CSS class applied to ASP.NET 4 Menu with RenderingMode=List

Tags: asp.net, css, menu, .net-4.0

I am using an ASP.NET 4.0 Menu control with RenderingMode=List and am struggling with creating the appropriate CSS.  Each menu item is represented by an <li> tag that contains a nested <a> tag with what appear to be fixed class names:

- <a class="level1"> for unselected level 1 menu items
- <a class="level2"> for unselected level 2 menu items
- <a class="level1 selected"> for the selected level 1 menu item

... etc...

What I want to do is to is to prevent the currently selected menu item from being "clickable".  To do so I tried using:

```
if (menuItem.Selected) menuItem.Selectable = false;
```

This has the desired effect of removing the href attribute from the <a> tag but also removes the class attribute - and as a result my CSS can not identify what level the menu item belongs to!

Looks to me like a possible bug, but in any case I can't find any documentation describing what CSS class names are used, nor whether there is any way to control this (the old Style properties don't appear to have any effect).  Ideally I would like to have "level" class attributes on the <li> tags, not just the nested <a> tags.

**UPDATE**

I've taken a look at the System.Web source with Reflector, and it appears that it does explicitly skip outputting CSS attributes if Selectable=false.  The following is extracted from `MenuRendererStandards.RenderItemLinkAttributes`:

```
...
if (!item.Selectable)
{
    return needsAccessKey; // !! exits without setting class attribute
}
if (item.Selected)
{
    cssClass = cssClass + " selected";
}
writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, cssClass);
...
```

Comment: Look at the output using Firebug or similar and see what html/classes are actually being output.

Comment: "Look at the output ..."?? I know what the output is and have described it above.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `HtmlTextWriterAttribute` class in `System.Web.UI` namespace, so that you write the attributes that you want.

I hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

After I found this out on my own, I got the explanation from the UPDATE of the original post. Thank you for this!
I check for the [current .net implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/MenuRendererStandards.cs) and have good news on this :)

```
   ...
   if (!item.Selectable){
      writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, cssClass);
      return needsAccessKey;
   }

  // Selected
  if (item.Selected) {
      cssClass += " selected";
  }
  writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, cssClass);
```

I hope this is helpful for somebody.